# Android - Installing Pager Sliding Tab Strip in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to install the Pager Sliding Tab Strip library and demo app into eclipse, but I get errors on installation and compile errors.

the library is here: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

What I have done is:

- downloaded the zip file from github,
- unzipped it into a folder on my windows PC,
- in Eclipse selected File|Import, Existing Android Code into Workspace, Next, browsed to the root directory `\PageSlidingTabStrip-master`
- Copy projects into workspace
- finish

This leads to an error:

```
Android SDK: Resolving error markers' has encountered a problem.
Marker id 3158 not found.
```

However, a node in my package explorer tree is created for each of the library and the demo project, but the have compile errors.

What does the reported error mean? Am I doing something wrong? What is the correct way to use this library in Eclipse?

Comment: "What does the reported error mean?" -- that is usually coming from more of a bug in the development tools. Your flagged compile errors, whatever they are, will be more relevant.

Comment: thank you ... I was thinking the compile errors would be a result of the import errors. All the errors are that a public method must override a superclass method.  The quick fix given is to remove the @override directive for the method, which naturally, doesn't work.

Comment: The usual cause of the "must override a superclass method" errors is because your Eclipse project is set up to validate against Java 1.5 syntax, and `@Override` on an interface method was added in Java 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. File->New->Other
2. Select Android Project
3. Select "Create Project from existing source"
4. Click "Browse..." and navigate to "PagerSlidingTabStrip-master" folder which you have downloaded from https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip
5. Check "library"! (Uncheck "sample"). Make sure "Copy to Workspace" is checked as well.
6. Click Finish. Now "library" is added to your workspace as a project. There are some errors detected but ignore them. You can right click on "library", go to "Refactor", and change it to "Lip_PagerSlidingTabStrip" (optional).
7. Right-click on your project -> Properties
8. In Android -> Library section, click "Add"
9. Select recently added "library" project, click Ok and you're all set. Make sure "Is library" in this window is unchecked.

EDIT

10. If you have faced an error subject to "Project cannot be build until the build path is correct", try to Quick Fix it by this option: "Add android.v4.supprt to Lib_PagerSlidingTabStrip."